# Android fragment animation doesn't actually finish

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I encountered this annoying problem, where I have 2 fragments, and I am running 3d flip animation on Fragments `getView()` component. Problem comes here, when the flip is done, I try to set another view invisible, but nothing happens. It seems that the animation is still on for the view and if I `setAnimation(null)` or `clearAnimation` for the view, the whole view is reset to start state.

I also did a little test, with just running alpha animation for the view and after that I cannot change the view visibility anymore. Any solution or hack for this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Here is small code snippet to reproduce problem.

Following code is ran when Fragment `onCreateView` has been called and button is clicked:

`AlphaAnimation fadeHalf = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.5f);
    fadeHalf.setFillAfter(true);`

```
fadeHalf.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
});

getView().startAnimation(fadeHalf);
```

So when running the code above, whole fragment view gets translated to 0.5f alpha, but `setVisilibity(View.GONE)` does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is what you need but you can probably remove the view and add it back on when you do the same animation in the future.

Comment: Didn't have to remove view, just clear animation and then set visibility. Your solution should work too.